# How can I embed a PDF on a website real size without scrolling?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I try to include fragments of pdf documents in a web page. These fragments are of different sizes. I want to display them in full in actual sizes.

I am looking to program in javascript something like:

```
<embed src="my_document.pdf#zoom=100" width="my_document.pdf".width height="my_document.pdf".height />
```

I do not know how to retrieve the document size in meta-datas of my document in javascript.

I have no problem to display the pdf. This code works but the 100% is 100% of the web page not the pdf document.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't do this with javascript. If your pdf documents are with text and pages you can set an attribute `page_count="N"`, which is accessable by javascript. Multiply it by "842 * zoomlvl" (A4 pixel height)

Comment: If you make a answer with your comment, I can accept it. The unit is pixel?

Comment: You can find paper sizes here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size. To get pixel height use: ceil(72.00 * paper_height_inches). So A4 = 11.69 * 72 ~= 842.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't do this with javascript**

Perhaps your able to get some meta-data like filesize, and file type (application/pdf) at best. 'Unrolling' the pdf contents to get a width/height isn't really standard so I doubt it is even in the meta-data.

**Possible solution**

If your pdf documents contain text and have a layout where each page is of the same height AND you have access to the amount of pages there are in the pdf. If so you can add an attribute `<embed page_type='A4' page_count='$page_count' ..`, which is accessable by javascript.

An A4 paper would be 842px (let's call it paper_height), so you can do something like pdf_height = paper_height * page_count * zoom;

**Optional stuff **

I am assuming the zoom is something custom, so you can add a javascript handler on it:

```
$('embed').height(paper_height * zoom);

// or

$('embed').css('height', paper_height * zoom);
```

However you might use some pre-defined CSS classes if the zoom does not have too many states. At the start you could do `<embed class='pdf_height_no_zoom' ..`. And if the user clicks a zoom button `$('embed').attr('class', 'pdf_zoom_level2');`